# Expression Builder giving different values for a field in Percent, Fixed and General Number formats

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, expressionbuilder

I am using Expression Builder to set the value for a calculated field which is supposed to be a percentage. In Expression Builder, this is my statement be executed

```
Usage: ((([UsedHeight]*[UsedWidth])/([Length]*[Width]))*100)
```

While selecting the field, in Query design View, I go to `Property Sheet` so as to set the `Format` of the field as `Percent`. The problem is once I change the format to `Percent` I get value of the field as `4444.44%`. If I set the `Format` of the field to `General Number` and run the query, I get 44.44444444 which is the exact value. If I change to `Fixed` Format then I get `44.44` which is the correct value. 
I have also tried using

```
 Usage: ([UsedHeight]*[UsedWidth])/([Length]*[Width])*100
```

but I face the same issue.
The values I use for the respective fields are like so

```
   (50*50)/(75*75)*100
```

which should return 44.444444.

Why is Ms Access 2007 wrongly computing the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Format as percent"* takes a decimal value and expresses it as a percent. For example, `.5` would display as `50%` using that format property.

So, if you want to apply percent format, don't first multiply by 100 ... use this instead:

```
Usage: ([UsedHeight]*[UsedWidth])/([Length]*[Width])
```

Or if you want to multiply by 100 in the field expression, choose a different format.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea that `Percent` property takes the value in the field and multiplies it by 100 before expressing it as a percentage/.